# How can I return a string from an Ienumerable?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, ienumerable

I am very new to programming and am taking an Object Oriented Programming class. However, the professor didn't explain how to take an Ienumerable and make it into a string in order to accomplish this question of the assignment:

> TODO:
> Write a public static C# method named NumSquare that takes a one-dimentional array as input
> and creates a LINQ statement that queries the numbers that have a square number graeter than 20 and orders them ascending.
> The LINQ query retrieves anonymous objects in which each object contains the number (Num) and its square number (SqrNum).
> The method returns the LINQ query as an IEnumerable object.
> The anonymous object contains two instance variables named Num and SqrNum.
> Input: a one-dimentional integer array.
> Output: a LINQ query of type IEnumerable.
> Example: Given array A = [3, 4, 10, 5], invoking NumSquare(A) return a LINQ query that once executed will contain:
> {Num=5, SqrNum=25},
> {Num=10, SqrNum=25}

Here's what I have so far, but I've tried several things over the last 2 1/2 weeks.

```
        public static IEnumerable<object> NumSquare(int[] A)
        {
            //write your code here

            var num = from Number in A
                      select Number;
            var sqrnum = from Number in A
                         let squarenum = Number * Number
                         select squarenum;
            
            return (IEnumerable<object>)sqrnum;
        }
```

I know that this return won't get me the whole result that I need, but that's as far as I can get with no errors. I also don't know how to test anything because he didn't show us how to call an IEnumerable. Help?

Comment: you can't *take* an eunerable. An enuerable is just a collection of items, in your case a collection of numbers. You can take a couple of those items, however it's not clear to me what you want to "make into a string". What does your code currently do and what *should* it do instead?

Comment: Thinking it's a typo but why would `{Num=10, SqrNum=25}` be in the result set

Comment: Why do you think a string is involved here or needs to be returned somewhere?

Comment: `sqrnum` is already an enumerable. You just need to research how to project into anonymous objects.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is not a string as output but as the exercise says an anonymous object. An anonymous object can be something like this:

```
var o = new { Num = 4, SqrNum = 16 };
```

Its just an object that basically has no explicit type and some read-only variables.

So what you want to do is to convert your array into a `IEnumerable<{int Num, int SqrNum}>` which you would have to declare as `IEnumerable<object>` and not a string.

You could do something like this:

```
static IEnumerable<object> NumSqr(int[] a)
{
    return a
        .Where(x => x * x > 20)
        .OrderBy(x => x)
        .Select(x => new { Num = x, SqrNum= x * x });
}
```

Alternatively:

```
static IEnumerable<object> NumSqr(int[] a)
{
    return from number in a
        where number * number > 20
        orderby number
        select new { Num = number, SqrNum = number * number };
}
```

In order to print out the result of the function you could do this:

```
var a = new int[] { 3, 4, 10, 5 };
var result = NumSqr(a);
foreach (var obj in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
}
```

The output should look like this:

```
{ Num = 5, SqrNum = 25 }
{ Num = 10, SqrNum = 100 }
```